# add_post_meta does not respect the content

Tags: mysql

I insert this and it works fine:

```php
add_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'robots', 'TEXT', true );
```

After adding that, I check the database and everything is fine, the result is **TEXT**.

But if I insert this:

```php
add_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'robots', 'a:2:{i:0;s:7:"noindex";i:1;s:8:"nofollow";}', true );
```

The result is:

```
s:43:"a:2:{i:0;s:7:"noindex";i:1;s:8:"nofollow";}";
```

And I need the result to be exactly the same as I have added it:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:7:"noindex";i:1;s:8:"nofollow";}
```

I need not to automatically add that **s:43:"** and the **";** at the end.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: I have solved it using unserialize(). Example: add_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'robots', unserialize('a:2:{i:0;s:7:"noindex";i:1;s:8:"nofollow";}'), true );

Comment: Does my revised answer answer your question? If so, I'd appreciate if you can mark my answer as "correct" - that way, it'll be clear to others that the question has an accepted solution. Or maybe, just +1 (upvote) my answer? :)

Comment: Sorry @SallyCJ I don't have much experience in stackexchange, but I have already marked your answer as correct :) Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why the content is not being respected

And *it's not just `add_post_meta()`, but any functions like `add_term_meta()` and `add_user_meta()` that uses [`add_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_metadata/)*.

And the reason why the value gets serialized again is because `add_metadata()` will automatically serialize the meta value using [`maybe_serialize()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_serialize/) which (unfortunately) will serialize the value even if it's already serialized.

### How to tackle the issue

In your case, if possible, pass an array instead of the serialized value/string:

```php
// A non-scalar value will be automatically serialized by maybe_serialize().
$value = array( 'noindex', 'nofollow' );

add_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'robots', $value, true );
```

However, if you retrieved/received the value from somewhere and you need to retain its exact format when saving, then — as you've already figured it out — you'll need to unserialize the value before passing it to `add_post_meta()` to prevent the double serialization.

But in WordPress, instead of using the native `unserialize()` function in PHP, I suggest you to use [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/) instead:

```php
$value = 'a:2:{i:0;s:7:"noindex";i:1;s:8:"nofollow";}';

// Unserialize the value and pass it to add_post_meta().
add_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'robots', maybe_unserialize( $value ), true );
```